# Finding author of a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

If someone writes "?name (arg)" I want my bot to say the author of the message + ", your name is" + arg. **I can't find of the author of the message** though.

```
@client.command()
async def name(their_name):
    await client.say("{0}, your name is {1}.".format("""author of the message goes here""", their_name))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the name of the author of the message, you will need to use [context](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/context.py#L35)

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def name(ctx):
    username = ctx.message.author.name
    ...
```

Comment: wait doesn't ctx.author.name also works? I tried with my bot and it returned the right value.

Comment: Both work. I just went with this form because I know for certain that `message` is a part of `ctx`, as I personally use stock discord.py in my bot, rather than `ext.commands`, which is what provides the `command()` decorator and the default `ctx` object.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`User.display_name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.display_name), which will try to to use the users server-specific nickname, but will fall back to the general username if that is not found:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def name(ctx):
    username = ctx.message.author.display_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can also use .mention, so if you will send it to the channel it will tag the author

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def name(ctx):
    username = ctx.message.author.mention
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the name of the author of the message you can use the:

```
message.author.id
```

Comment: I tried this code and it said message is not defined, so I defined message at the top of my code and now it says str has no attribute author.